# Twint for Python just stops scraping

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, twint

I'm currently using Twint in Powershell from Anaconda.

My python version is 3.6 and I've updated Twint  just yesterday with

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade -e git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint
```

I have a problem right now.

I'm using this code

```
twint -s "pinches hondureños" --since 2018-10-22 -o file.json --json
```

At first it shows me some tweets that have been made in the past days, but it just stops and says the following:

```
[!] No more data! Scraping will stop now.
found 0 deleted tweets in this search.
```

I know that there are more tweets with that phrase, but Twint does not collect them, has anyone had this problem before? And if you had, How did you resolve it?

Comment: maybe first visit GitHub with [source code](https://github.com/twintproject/twint) and check [issues](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues) - maybe someone had this problem.

Comment: source code is almost 1 year old - maybe twitter changed something on page or in API and code needs updates ?

Comment: Please don't arbitrarily mark words as `code`. See [ask] and take the [tour] to learn more.